# Cannot expand Grandchild in Qtreeview PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, treeview, qt5

I want to have excel pivot view (in the following picture) where I can do expand and collapse in PyQt.

[image]

A child item is expanded (in the following picture) if the root item is clicked. But, if the child item is clicked, it won't trigger further expansion which will shows the grandchildren.
[image]

Here is my code that I have written:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class GroupView(QtWidgets.QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, model, parent=None):
        super(GroupView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setIndentation(0)
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked) #Item Click trigger expand or collapse
        self.setModel(model)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QModelIndex)
    def on_clicked(self, index):
        self.setExpanded(index, not self.isExpanded(index))
            
class GroupModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GroupModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setColumnCount(5)
        self.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Name", "Variant", "Colour", "Size", "Stock"]) #Set Header Name

    def add_items(self, key, item):
        ii = self.invisibleRootItem()
        i = ii.rowCount()
        
        ii.setEditable(False)
        
        # Insert Item on Product Name Level
        item_root = QtGui.QStandardItem(key)
        item_root.setEditable(False)
        
        item_total = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item['total']))
        item_total.setEditable(False)
        
        ii.setChild(i, 0, item_root)
        ii.setChild(i, 4, item_total)
        
        for idx1, (key1, item1) in enumerate(item['var'].items()):
            # Insert Item on Product Variant Level
            item_root1 =  QtGui.QStandardItem(key1)
            item_root1.setEditable(False)
            
            item_total1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item1['total']))
            item_total1.setEditable(False)
            
            item_root.setChild(idx1, 1, item_root1)
            item_root.setChild(idx1, 4, item_total1)
            
            for idx2, (key2, item2) in enumerate(item1['colour'].items()):
                # Insert Item on Product Colour Level
                item_root2 =  QtGui.QStandardItem(key2)
                item_root2.setEditable(False)
                
                item_total2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item2['total']))
                item_total2.setEditable(False)
                
                item_root1.setChild(idx2, 2, item_root2)
                item_root1.setChild(idx2, 4, item_total2)
                
                for idx3, (key3, item3) in enumerate(item2['size'].items()):
                    # Insert Item on Product Size Level
                    item_root3 =  QtGui.QStandardItem(key3)
                    item_root3.setEditable(False)
                    
                    item_total3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(item3))
                    item_total3.setEditable(False)
                    
                    item_root2.setChild(idx3, 3, item_root3)
                    item_root2.setChild(idx3, 4, item_total3)                    
                    
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        model = GroupModel(self)
        tree_view = GroupView(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(tree_view)
        
        product_dict = {'T-Shirt Minion': 
                            {'total': 510,
                             'var': 
                                {'Lengan Panjang': 
                                    {'total': 370,
                                     'colour': 
                                        {'Merah': 
                                            {'total': 370,
                                             'size': 
                                                {'S': 100, 
                                                 'L': 170, 
                                                 'M': 100
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                 'Lengan Pendek': 
                                    {'total': 140,
                                     'colour': 
                                        {'Merah': 
                                            {'total': 140, 
                                             'size': {}
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
    
        for key, item in product_dict.items():
            group_item = model.add_group(key, item)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(720, 240)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have searched several tutorials but still can't spot where my mistake is. Hope someone could help me with it.

Comment: TYPO: You're adding child items in the wrong column: the items that are also parents in turn should always be in column 0. That's quite clear even from your screenshot: "Lengan" items are under the second column.

Comment: I tried to add child in column 0 and it works. From my understanding, parents should always be in column 0 ? is it right ?

Comment: Yes. But that's pretty standard for any tree based view: you always open the leftmost item, even in children. The other columns are generally used for *details*. In fact, it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have a child in another column: if your model only had 2 columns, how would you expand beyond the second level?